# Triple Particles

Tags: particles

Double particles certainly occur in Japanese, but do triple particles ever occur?  And if so, what is their pitch pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I can think of 〜からには

- [What's the difference between 〜以上は and 〜からには](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2549/78)
- [What's the difference between からには, 以上, and 上は?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41565)

Also, 〜までには

> - かれがここへ着くまでには仕事を終えているでしょう　→　I will finish my job by the time he gets here

---

*Example sentence taken from スーパー大辞林 in macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but is から considered a particle?

Comment: So in には, the に is accented.  Do we have a succession of accented particles for the longer sequences?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Yes. 明鏡国語辞典 says the から in the phrase ～から(に)は is a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle). (Basically から as "from" is a case particle/格助詞, and から as "because" is a conjunctive particle)